# Перевод с кириллицы на латиницу для pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Так как метод `pyautogui.typewrite()` в Python не поддерживает русский язык.Мне надо чтобы слово привет конвертировалось в ghbdtn. Может есть конвертатор?

Comment: а откуда вы возьмёте 'привет' ? прогоните нужную строку через словарь {'й':'q' , 'ц':'w'} и тд

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```py
word = "привет"
conv = {
    'й':'q',
    'ц':'w',
    'у':'e',
    'к':'r',
    'е':'t',
    'н':'y',
    'г':'u',
    'ш':'i',
    'щ':'o',
    'з':'p',
    'х':'[',
    'ъ':']',
    'ф':'a',
    'ы':'s',
    'в':'d',
    'а':'f',
    'п':'g',
    'р':'h',
    'о':'j',
    'л':'k',
    'д':'l',
    'ж':';',
    'э':'\'',
    '\\':'\\',
    'я':'z',
    'ч':'x',
    'с':'c',
    'м':'v',
    'и':'b',
    'т':'n',
    'ь':'m',
    'б':',',
    'ю':'.',
    '.':'/',
}

pyautogui.typewrite(''.join(conv[k] for k in word))
```